# SpringBoot JPQL query List NotIn List

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Iam struggle with a MySQL DB query and hope you can help me.
The example is abstract since the problem is the query:

The POJOs:

```
class Parent
{
 List<Child> children;
}

class Child
{
 Integer id;
}
```

Now I want to find all Parents which NOT having certain children.

like:

```
List<Parent> findByChildrenNotIn(List<Child> childs);
```

or

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Parent p "
        + "LEFT OUTER JOIN p.children c "
        + "WHERE c.id != ?1 " 
        + "GROUP BY p.id "
        )
List<Parent> findByNotChildren(List<Integer> childIds);
```

Optionaly it would be OK to filter at least by on Child like:

```
List<Parent> findByChildrenNot(Child child);
```

or something like that.

It seems so easy, but I dont find a solution. Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Gregor

Comment: There is no `!=` in JPQL. It is `<>`, and you cannot do (in)equality on a List!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one child is enough use [`MEMBER OF`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_collection_member) like this:

```
@Query("select p from Parent p where :child NOT MEMBER OF p.childs")
List<Parent> findParents(@Param("child")Child child);
```

If you would have a bidirectional relationship you could query it like this:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT c.parent FROM Child c WHERE c NOT IN (:childs)")
List<Parent> findParents(@Param("childs")List<Child> childs);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work (not tested - please give a feedback):

```
List<Parent> findDistinctByChildrenIdNotIn(List<Integer> childIds);
```

or

```
@Query("select distinct p from Parent p left join p.children c where c.id not in ?1")
List<Parent> findParents(List<Integer> childIds);
```

More info: [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords), [2](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_in), [3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/c2cd87689f26b28c9ca5d1f368821baadc8323c6/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L143)